¿Por qué el programa no ejecuta las funciones de cadenas de texto a las que estoy llamando?
estoy haciendo este pequeño en C y estoy teniendo algunos problemas al momento de ejecutar las operaciones con cadenas. Les adjunto mi código:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TAM 10
#define FL '\n'
#define FC '\0'

void menu();
void leer_iniciales(char cad[]);
void point_iniciales(char iniciales[], char iniciales_mod[]);
void char_to_ASCII(char cad[]);

int main(){
    int run=1;
    int opcion;
    char iniciales[TAM], iniciales_con_puntos[TAM];
    
        menu();
        scanf("%i", &opcion);
        
        if (opcion==1) {
            leer_iniciales(iniciales);
            printf("%s\n", iniciales);
            point_iniciales(iniciales, iniciales_con_puntos);
            printf("%s\n", iniciales_con_puntos);
        
        }
        if(opcion==2){
            leer_iniciales(iniciales);
            char_to_ASCII(iniciales);
        }
        if(opcion != 1 && opcion!=2){
            printf("Introduce una opcion valida la proxima vez");
        }
    

    return 0;
}

void menu(){
    printf("%60s\n\n", "MENU PRINCPAL");
    printf("%40s\n","1.- Imprimir iniciales del nombre");
    printf("%40s\n","2.- Imprimir codigos ASCII del nombre");

    printf("\nSelecciona una opción (A o B): ");
}

void leer_iniciales(char cad[]){
    int c, i;

    printf("Escribe las iniciales de tu nombre: ");

    for(i=0; i<TAM-1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != FL; i++) {
        cad[i]=c;
    }
    if(c == FL) {
        cad[i]= FC;
    }
}

void point_iniciales(char iniciales[], char iniciales_mod[]){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0, j=0; i<TAM-1 && iniciales[j-1] != '\0'; i++){
        if(i%2==0){
            iniciales_mod[i]= iniciales[j];
            j++;
        }
        else
           iniciales_mod[i]= '.';
    }
}

void char_to_ASCII(char cad[]){
    for(int i=0; cad[i]!= FC; i++)
        printf("%c = %i  ", cad[i],cad[i]);
}

Quiero que el programa permita al usuario introducir sus iniciales y que se impriman (pero con puntos entre cada letra) o imprima el código ASCII de cada una de las iniciales. Sin embargo, al momento de que el usuario elige la opción. No se ejecuta los bloques de código dentro de las condicionales y vuelve al punto del menú.
No sé que estaré haciendo mal, agradecería mucho el apoyo para saber como resolver este error.

¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? problema con getchar en c

La referencia en el comentario es una solución y la explicación a tu problema. Lo que sucede es que getchar está leyendo el retorno de carro y por eso no se ejecuta tu código. Además de lo indicado en la respuesta de los comentarios te dejo una solución alternativa.
    char buf[128];
    fgets (buf, 128, stdin);
    sscanf (buf, "%i", &opcion);

La función fgets leerá toda la línea como una cadena de caracteres, incluyendo el retorno de carro. Luego usando sscanf puedes leer tu entero.
La función para poner los puntos a las iniciales parece no funcionar. Esta es una posible implementación:
void point_iniciales(char *p, char *q){
  while (*p) 
    if (!isblank (*p)) { *q++ = *p++;*q++ = '.';}
    else p++;
}

Esta versión utiliza punteros y elimina espacios en blanco incluyendo múltiples espacios o tabuladores. Debes añadir #include <ctype.h> al principio del programa para poder utilizar isblank.
La implementación considera que las iniciales están compuestas por una sola letra y que cuando el usuario entra varias letras juntas, cada una de ellas se interpretará como una inicial. Quizás tengas que modificar la función si tus especificaciones son diferentes.
Casos de Prueba
Entrada                  Salida
A B C                    A.B.C.
  A B C                  A.B.C.
  A   B   C              A.B.C.
A BC                     A.B.C.
  AB C                   A.B.C.
<TAB> A BC<TAB>          A.B.C.
<TAB>A<TAB><TAB>B C      A.B.C.

Nota: Probablemente deberías comprobar que las iniciales son caracteres válidos usando otras funciones de ctype.h
